# neo4j produces "No authorization header supplied" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, neo4j

I'm trying to access neo4j running on an aws ec2 instance from the command line where I get authorisation errors. I've enabled `org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0` and get a 503 error on the first statement and the same errors for the rest using the ec2 host name.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-192:/etc/neo4j$ curl http://localhost:7474/
{
  "management" : "http://localhost:7474/db/manage/",
  "data" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/"
}ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-192:/etc/neo4j$ curl http://localhost:7474/db/data/
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "No authorization header supplied.",
    "code" : "Neo.ClientError.Security.AuthorizationFailed"
  } ]
}ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-192:/etc/neo4j$ curl http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j/
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "No authorization header supplied.",
    "code" : "Neo.ClientError.Security.AuthorizationFailed"
  } ]
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-192:/etc/neo4j$ curl http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j/password
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "No authorization header supplied.",
    "code" : "Neo.ClientError.Security.AuthorizationFailed"
  } ]
```

Am I logging in correctly or have I missed a step somewhere?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For the auth APIs you still need authorization.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to provide authorization header in your request

```
Authorization: Basic bmVvNGo6bmVvNGo=

curl --header "Authorization: Basic bmVvNGo6bmVvNGo=" http://localhost:7474

bmVvNGo6bmVvNGo= is default Neo4j password: neo4j
```

by @michael-hunger

note: For the auth APIs you still need authorization.

```
curl -u neo4j:password http://localhost:7474
```

Or turn off authorization in Neo4j configuration

conf/neo4j-server.properties

```
# Disable authorization 
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```

Here is more information about that

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-security.html

Comment: Thanks that works from the command line however I have to disable authorisation to access remotely and I'm still getting a 503 error when accessing `http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7474/ `

Comment: or rather `curl -u neo4j:password`

Comment: What is the syntax to supply the password via the browser?

Comment: How do you provide authorization header? Input "Authorization: Basic bmVvNGo6bmVvNGo=..." in the web browser?

Comment: @ANguyen you can't by default, but you can use Postman, for example - https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: Can u give me advice? I type "http://localhost:7474/user/neo4j" on the web browser and receive "No authorization header supplied.". How can I view the neo4j information on web browser?

Comment: It should be noted that `bmVvNGo6bmVvNGo=` is just the base64 encoded `neo4j:neo4j`.

Comment: I was getting this error in Neo4j Browser, I have to hit the same query multiple times until suddenly / randomly it runs without error

Answer (score 1):

The steps below will construct an "Authorization" header that will work when curling Neo4j REST APIs. This works in Neo4j Community 4.4.7 (probably with earlier versions, too). Assuming that `username = "neo4j"` and `password = "am4zeftw"`:

1. You need to construct a base64 encoding of the username and password combination. If you use the correct format – "user:password" – as input into `base64`, you'll get a correctly formatted string as output. The example below generates `bmVvNGo6YW00emVmdHc=` for username "neo4j" and password "am4zeftw":

   ```
   echo -n 'neo4j:am4zeftw' | base64
   bmVvNGo6YW00emVmdHc=
   ```
2. Construct the header itself, using the output from `base64`:

   ```
   -H 'Authorization:Basic bmVvNGo6YW00emVmdHc='
   ```
3. Include that header in your `curl` command, like this:

   ```
   curl -H 'Authorization:Basic bmVvNGo6YW00emVmdHc=' \
   -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
   http://11.22.33.44:7474/db/data/transaction/commit -d "..."
   ```