# Neo4j produce No authorization error

Tags: curl, neo4j

I'm running curl on the Cygwin command window and is trying to create a node on Neo4j. I first got a no authorization error so I looked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966591/neo4j-produces-no-authorization-header-supplied-error#). Now my code is:

`curl -u new4j:mypassword http://localhost:7474 \
curl -i -H accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json -XPOST \
http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit -d \
'{"statements":[{"statement":"CREATE (p:Peach) RETURN p"}]}'`

However I'm still getting this error code:

[image]

Looks like Neo4j doesn't recogize 'curl' as a method. Any ideas of how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in the first line of code, you have used `new4j`. I think it should be `neo4j` if you have not changed the username.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer. It should be

`curl --user neo4j:mypassword -i -H accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json -XPOST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit -d  '{"statements":[{"statement":"CREATE (p:Peach) Return p"}]}'`